# Finite generation of motivic cohomology of number fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, motives, tate-motives

Let $F$ be a number field ($F=\mathbb Q$ is fine for my purposes) and let $n\geq2$ be an integer. Is it known whether the first motivic cohomology groups
$$\mathrm H^1(\mathrm{Spec}(F),\mathbb Z(n))$$
are finitely generated? We know that they are finite-dimensional after tensoring with $\mathbb Q$, since they become identified with the rational $K$-theory $K_{2n-1}(F)_{\mathbb Q}$ whose dimension was computed by Borel. But are they finitely generated integrally? A reference, if it exists, would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's true? I'd expect to see lots of torsion classes coming from local Euler factors.

Comment: What I do know is that the $K$-group $K_{2n-1}(F)$ is finitely generated integrally, and that there is a spectral sequence whose $E_2$ page consists of the motivic cohomology groups, converging to the $K$-groups. So finite generation of motivic cohomology, if true, would at least explain finite generation of the $K$-groups. But I don't have any direct reason to expect this to be true (and am equally interested to know if it's false).

Comment: Can you give a reference for the K-group statement?

Comment: The dimensions of the rational K-theory groups of a number field were computed by Borel, not Bloch.

Comment: @naf Of course, thanks! Corrected now.

Comment: @David Loeffler You mean the finite generation? I learned this from Chuck Weibel's article "Algebraic $K$-Theory of Rings of Integers in Local and Global Fields" in the Handbook of $K$-theory, which even gives an explicit description of these integral $K$-groups. It's available on his website at https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~weibel/papers-dir/KZsurvey-published.pdf

Comment: Bloch-Kato tells us what the motivic cohomology of a field with finite coefficients is in terms of étale cohomology, so your statement is essentially equivalent to asking that $H^p_{ét}(F;\mu_l^{\otimes q})$ is finitely generated for every $p,q$ and prime $l$.

Comment: In fact if you're interested only on $H^1$, it's enough to ask it for $p=1$.

Comment: @DenisNardin $H^1(F, \mathbb{Z}(n))$ could be finitely generated and $H^2(F, \mathbb{Z}(n))$ be infinitely generated and all motivic cohomolgy with torsion coefficients be infinitely generated. What you mention only proves all cohomology groups cannot be finitely generated. Unless we know that Bockstein morphisms are zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, I believe it is known that these are finitely generated.  First, the Gysin sequence shows that the map
$$H^1(\mathcal{O}_F;\mathbb{Z}(n))\rightarrow H^1(F;\mathbb{Z}(n))$$
is injective with cokernel given by
$$\oplus_\nu H^0(k_\nu;\mathbb{Z}(n-1))$$
where $\nu$ runs over all maximal ideals of $\mathcal{O}_F$ with residue field $k_\nu$.  As we assumed $n\geq 2$, this direct sum vanishes, so the question is equivalent to showing that $H^1(\mathcal{O}_F;\mathbb{Z}(n))$ is finitely generated.  But now that we've replaced $F$ by $\mathcal{O}_F$, this finite generation actually holds in any degree and weight.

Indeed, the K-groups of $\mathcal{O}_F$ are finitely generated as shown by Quillen (a "simple" argument is to use homological stability to reduce to showing that the homology groups of general linear groups over $\mathcal{O}_F$ are finitely generated, which follows from Borel-Serre).  Now, the spectral sequence from motivic cohomology to K-theory degenerates rationally by the Adams operations, but in fact more is true, as noted by Kahn: it degenerates "up to isogeny".  So K-theory and motivic cohomology can only differ by bounded torsion.  Thus, to deduce finite generation of motivic cohomology from that of K-theory, it suffices to see that (mod $p$) motivic cohomology of $\mathcal{O}_K$ is finitely generated for any prime $p$, in any degree and weight.  By another application of Gysin and the fact that mod $p$ motivic cohomology of a finite field of characteristic $p$ is only nontrivial when degree = weight = zero, this reduces to the same claim for $\mathcal{O}_K[1/p]$.  Now we are in the Bloch-Kato regime where we can compare to etale cohomology, but we should take a bit of care because $\mathcal{O}_K$ is not itself a field.  But if you compare Gysin sequences for motivic cohomology and etale cohomology and use Bloch-Kato for the quotient field and residue fields, you do indeed see that the claim reduces to the finiteness of etale cohomology of $\mathcal{O}_K[1/p]$ with $\mathbb{F}_p(n)$-coefficients.

Comment: This looks close to what I was hoping for! Which of Kahn's papers makes this observation about the motivic cohomology spectral sequence? And do you have a good reference for the vanishing of mod $p$ motivic cohomology of finite fields?

Comment: I can’t recover the Kahn reference right now, but Levine’s paper https://conf.math.illinois.edu/K-theory/0336/ should have the relevant info on Adams operations. And Geisser-Levine https://www.uni-due.de/~bm0032/publ/pfield.pdf should have the info on mod p motivic cohomology in char p.

Comment: I followed this up with Bruno Kahn, and he pointed me to Theorem 40 of his chapter in the Handbook of $K$-Theory, which exactly proves this finite generation result for motivic cohomology of rings of integers over number fields. (And indeed proves it along the lines you suggest.)

Answer (score 3):

By the Beilinson–Lichtenbaum conjecture (which is now a theorem), this group is just isomorphic to the corresponding etale (which is also Galois) cohomology one if $n\ge 1$ and zero for $n=0$ (as noted earlier by Denis Nardin).

To my surprise, this appears to imply that for $n\ge 1$ this group is infinite; see [Infiniteness of the Galois cohomology over a number field with coefficients in a finite Galois module](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239493/infiniteness-of-the-galois-cohomology-over-a-number-field-with-coefficients-in-a)

Comment: I am very bad in computing these degrees; sorry.:) It appears that $n>0$ is the correct inequality.

Comment: This is not correct, because the question is about integral motivic cohomology.

Comment: Yes, you are right; this is an answer for cohomology with torsion coefficients. Yet it shouldn't be very difficult to obtain the integral answer using torsion information.